# WinApi How to get the MouseWheel Notch?

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, mouse

Hello I'm currently making a game with DirectX and I'm having trouble getting the mouse wheels current notch or something similar. I looked up for a small example and I couldn't find one that really worked. I saw that they were using the Windows Message WM_MOUSEWHEEL but I have problems getting the current notch, please help.

Comment: The scroll amount is in multiples of 120. Each 120 represents one notch.

Comment: So how would I handle all that?

Comment: You can get the total amount via `GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam)` and use that to figure out what multiple of `WHEEL_DELTA` (120) you have. Positive values mean it was rotated forward, and negative values mean it was rotated backward. Be aware that there are mice that scroll less than one notch, though.

Comment: And how exactly would you do it in code. You might aswell post it as an answer to this question maybe?

Comment: You seem to assume it has an absolute position.  It doesn't, its a wheel.  You only get incremental changes.

Comment: @ArtursLapins, *Are* you trying to keep track of the position? In that case, keep a variable and increment it or decrement it every time you get a `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message.

Comment: I was thinking of that but was not sure how to be sure if it moved forward or backward and I would like an example of using WHEEL_DELTA since it tells you that.

Comment: @ArtursLapins, You can do something like `int delta = GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam); tracker += delta;` and use `tracker / WHEEL_DELTA` to get the current notch that you've tracked.

Comment: Hmm didn't seem to work well.
I did that but then I created a if statement if the delta is bigger than 2 then stop the program and it only stoped when i notched the mouse forward like without even counting the notches, like you would scroll through a web browser

Comment: @ArtursLapins, 2 notches forward is a delta of `2 * WHEEL_DELTA`, or 240. Two backward is -240. You can use `std::abs` and check if that's greater than 2 notches to not care which direction it is.

Answer (score 1):

Mouse wheels do not have a "current notch" so there's no way to query for such a thing from that device.  They only measure change delta and direction and this information will be included in the event you get when it is moved.  If there is a "current notch" it is in your program and you'll have to track it yourself.  This might come in the form of a zoom factor, a page position, or whatever.